# Check if a big object have null value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a function to go through an object and if is there any null values. Here is my code:

```
  async function validateObjectField(course) {
  let error = new Error();
  const keys = Object.keys(course);
  keys.forEach(k => {
    const obj = course[k];
    if (typeof obj === "object") {
      if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        if (Object.size(obj) === 0) {
          error.message = `${obj} is required!`;
          return error;
        }
        for (const o of obj) {
          error = validateObjectField(o);
          if (error) return error;
        }
      } else {
        error = validateObjectField(obj);
        if (error) return error;
      }
    }
    if ((typeof obj === "string" && obj.length === 0) || obj === null) {
      error.message = `${obj} is required!`;
      return error;
    }
  });
}
```

I'm using console.log() to observe and see that sometimes the code goes to return statement but the remaining code is still executed. Anyone know why? I got stuck and have no idea what to do now.

In this block of codes:

```
if (obj.length === 0) {
    error.message = `${obj} is required!`;
    return error;
}
```

It did not return the error and break the function.

Comment: `return`ing from a forEach won't do anything except terminate the *current* iteration early. Use something like `for..of` instead, or `.find`. Could also use `JSON.stringify` - feels kind of weird, but would trim down the code a LOT

Comment: I change to forEach, but it still not work

Comment: You were already using `forEach`, but the fundamental problem is that you can't break out of a `forEach`

Comment: So is there any solution? I want to return a custom error but not the false or true like in the answer

Comment: Yes, like I said, use `.find` or `for..of` instead

Comment: I change it, and sorry but I updated the question, can you view it again? thank you

Comment: You are still using `forEach`, but you cannot break out of a `forEach` - see the linked question. (unless you `throw` an error, which is a bad idea)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I changed to for..of, but when it reach the block of codes as I asked, it did not return the error

Comment: You're still using `forEach`, which you can't break out of: `keys.forEach(k => {` Use `for..of` instead there

Comment: You are *still* using `keys.forEach(k => {`, which is the problem.

Comment: ah, I did not notice that. Sorry too much, thanks for your patient